# MVC - Input string was not in a correct format - Application_Error - Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax, application-error

I do not know where this exception is being thrown.
I intercept the exception in Application_Error.
Application_Error is called after the page is fully loaded.
It occurs on any page.

Code of Application_Error:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                string errorMessage = "";
                LogServices logServ = new LogServices();

                Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
                string exMsg = exception.Message;
                Exception _ex = exception.InnerException;
                while(null != _ex)
                {
                    exMsg = string.Format("{0} {1}", exMsg, _ex.Message);
                    _ex = _ex.InnerException;
                }



                string logId = logServ.log(exception, "", Context.Request.UserAgent);

                if (exMsg.IndexOf("was not found") != -1)
                {
                    errorMessage = ElizeuSites.AssimEstaEscrito.Resources.Global.PageNotFound;
                    Server.ClearError();
                    string urlRedirect = String.Format("/FrontEnd/{0}/{1}?{2}={3}&errorMessage={4}", "Error", "PopUpError", "logId", logId, errorMessage);
                    Server.TransferRequest(urlRedirect);
                }
}
```

Captured with error Server.GetLastError():

"Input string was not in a correct format "

Stack Trace:

```
 em System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   em System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectorIfUnique(List`1 elements, String selectorFormatString)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectorsFromIds(List`1 elements, String selectorFormatString)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectorsInternal(IEnumerable`1 elements, String selectorFormatString, Func`2 isUniqueTagName, Boolean indexAsLastResort)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectors(IEnumerable`1 elements)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.ProcessDataIntoJsonObjects(IEnumerable`1 renderedOutputList)
   em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: What are the values of `logId` and `errorMessage`?

Comment: Try to add `~` before `/FrontEnd/` and check `logId`, `errorMessage`

Comment: The error does not occur in Application_Error. This code is ok. I just intercept the error in this method. The problem is that this error occurs somewhere in the system, and even debugging I can not find the exact location. It can be a String.Format somewhere. I thought it might be in layout.cshtml because happen on any page.

Comment: Stack Trace not show my code. This is not common.

Comment: You can put a break point in Application_Error and try to find out offending URL and then debug that specific view or partial view. Something like :  http://technobird.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/file-not-found-exception-in.html . This is not specific to your error but you will get the idea,

Comment: As I put the question and explained in the commentary, the Application_Error method, which is the only place that I capture the error. I expected that the stack trace was possible that someone has been through this and know how to answer. Scoring negative, just because you can not answer does not help me.

Comment: Have you ever heard about [CallStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx)?

Comment: No, what is CallStack?

Comment: Special for you there is a link (blue text). And the problem in your question but not in our answers.

Comment: Show me how to use the "CallStack" within Application_Error using Server.GetLastError (). :P

Comment: Hakunamatata, Your awnser was useful. The ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request.Url  return this -> h t t p : / / localhost:5757/__browserLink/requestData/1bc6f5af4c4e421fbed35fefb631474a

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the tip of Hakunamatata I saw that the problem was browserlink. In the MSDN blog(L[ink of blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx)) It has the full explanation of the browserlink. I could solve the problem with the configuration below.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
```